# The double from validated test doesn't match the out.prinln version

Tags: java, junit, double, decimal

I have encountered an intriguing problem. I am building an application dealing with selling burgers. My tests in JUnit pass so far. However, I have noticed that the results of jUnit don't really match the printed versions of the same numbers.

Moreover, the results of my calculations come from rather simple operations like adding and subtracting pretty simple doubles - why I get results like e.g. 11.8999999999 instead of 11.90?

Test file that passes

```
@Test
public void canGenerateAndCountProccessedTransactions2(){
    till1.newTransaction();
    till1.addProduct(burger1);//3.00
    till1.addProduct(burger2);//4.60
    till1.addProduct(burger3);//4.30
    till1.completeTransaction();
    assertEquals(11.90, till1.getIncome(), 0.1);
    till1.newTransaction();
    till1.addProduct(burger1);//3.00
    till1.addProduct(burger1);//3.00
    till1.addProduct(burger1);//3.00
    till1.completeTransaction();
    assertEquals(20.90, till1.getIncome(), 0.1);
    assertEquals(2, till1.numOfProcessedTransactions());
}
```

Printed result of the tested method

```
Income so far is 11.899999999999999. Transaction value: 11.899999999999999
Income so far is 20.9. Transaction value: 9.0
```

Tested method

```
public void completeTransaction(){
     double value = 0.0;
     for(Burger product : this.transaction.keySet()){
        for(int i=0; i<(int)(this.transaction.get(product)); i++){
            double price = calculateBurgerPrice(product);
            this.income += (double) price;
            value += price;
            this.soldBurgers += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Income so far is " + getIncome() + ". Transaction 
    value: " + value);
    this.processedTransactions += 1;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: 11.90 cannot be presented in a finite number of bits with a double. That is because a floating point value is a sum of (negative) powers of 2. One either has to use BigDecimal as in `new BigDecimal("11.90")` or keep rounding and rounding.

Comment: I definitely need to read more about that. I will give it a go! Thanks :)

Comment: `assertEquals(20.90, till1.getIncome(), 0.1)` has a very large delta. It implies you don't really care about even the first digit after the decimal point. It would treat 1.25 and 1.5 as being equal. You could make it much smaller without the assertions failing.

Answer (score 0):

They do match since the precision that you set allows for such a small change.
You should rather round the double to the precision you need (say 1e-2) and print that rather than the double itself (untested):

```
System.out.println("Income so far is %.2f. Transaction value: %.2f", getIncome(), value);
```

Comment: You might want to use a smaller precision in your tests too. You wouldn't want to pay $0.10 extra :)

Comment: I will try that solution but I still don't get how 3.30 + 5.30 could be 8.59999999999999999999999999 instead of 8.60 :)

Comment: As it has been suggested before, read a bit more about what exactly is a double and how numbers are represented in floating points :)